# MongoDB dynamically conditional filtering

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to create a form builder and generator and from generated forms, I will collect answers. After collecting answers I want to filter them according to some filter parameters and get average results for each category.

Questions have categories(attributeGroupOne&Two) bind to them.

I have the following structure for my answers.

```
{
    "form": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62295d028b6b895048b7da96"
        },
        "questionType": "lickert5",
        "label": "deneme sorusu 1",
        "attributeGroupTwo": "deneme kategorisi alt 2",
        "attributeGroupOne": "deneme kategorisi",
        "name": "Question_1",
        "weight": 4,
        "type": "radio",
        "options": {
            "1": "Çok Az",
            "2": "Az",
            "3": "Bazen",
            "4": "Genellikle",
            "5": "Her Zaman"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62295d028b6b895048b7da95"
        },
        "questionType": "lickert10",
        "label": "deneme sorusu 2",
        "attributeGroupTwo": "deneme alt 3",
        "attributeGroupOne": "deneme kategorisi",
        "name": "Question_2",
        "weight": 4,
        "type": "radio",
        "options": {
            "1": "1",
            "2": "2",
            "3": "3",
            "4": "4",
            "5": "5",
            "6": "6",
            "7": "7",
            "8": "8",
            "9": "9",
            "10": "10"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62295d028b6b895048b7da94"
        },
        "questionType": "trueFalse",
        "label": "deneme sorusu 3",
        "attributeGroupTwo": "deneme alt 5",
        "attributeGroupOne": "deneme kategorisi",
        "name": "Question_3",
        "weight": 4,
        "type": "radio",
        "options": {
            "0": "Yanlış",
            "10": "Doğru"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62295d028b6b895048b7da93"
        },
        "questionType": "lickert5",
        "label": "deneme sorusu 4",
        "attributeGroupTwo": "deneme main sub",
        "attributeGroupOne": "deneme main 2",
        "name": "Question_4",
        "weight": 4,
        "type": "radio",
        "options": {
            "1": "Çok Az",
            "2": "Az",
            "3": "Bazen",
            "4": "Genellikle",
            "5": "Her Zaman"
        }
    }],
    "surveyName": "deneme formu",
    "createdBy": {
        "$oid": "61becc2c230fc12274683b6a"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2022-03-10T02:05:54.039Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2022-03-10T02:05:54.039Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT2Cq.png

Without additional filter just by filtering category with following query I am getting reports that I wanted.

```
      .aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$answers' },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$answers.SubCategory',
            CalculatedWeight: { $avg: '$answers.CalculatedWeight' },
            formId: { $first: formId }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 1, CalculatedWeight: 1, formId: 1 } },
        { $out: 'results' }
      ])
```

results:

```
{
    "CalculatedWeight": 19.35483870967742,
    "formId": {
        "$oid": "62295d028b6b895048b7da92"
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxqBe.png

I successfully added age filtering with following block

```
const docs = await model
      .aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { age: { $gt: minAge, $lt: maxAge } },
              { formId: { $eq: formId } }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $unwind: '$answers' },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$answers.SubCategory',
            CalculatedWeight: { $avg: '$answers.CalculatedWeight' },
            formId: { $first: formId }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 1, CalculatedWeight: 1, formId: 1 } },
        { $out: 'results' }
      ])
```

But I have 5 filters that are, gender, department, age, working years, and education level. If possible I want to be able to combine them with dynamic querying but I don't want to write 120 if cases for combining them. I can't think a way to programmatically filter and calculate according to filters.

Thank you in advance. The question itself might be unclear, sorry about it. I can elaborate if you point out where it is lacking.

Edit:
Filter types can be seen below. Age and working years will be a period with min and max values. If possible I want to be able to combine all filter types but it will probably statistically unreasonable due to the small pool of entries ~200. Most common combinations for filters are: Gender-Department-Age, Working Years- Department, Education - Gender.

Filters:
gender: String - enum
department: String - enum
age: Number - Min and Max
working years: Number - Min and Max
education: String - enum

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Instead, post valid json documents.

Comment: Fair point edited my post. Thank you!

Comment: There are still some images left unchanged. And, it would be helpful if you can provide the input values for filters, e.g. what could be one of the filter combinations? what is supplied if the filter is not specified? null or other values?

Comment: Thank you again, added further information about filter types. Unchanged images are the representations of code blocks above them in MongoDB compass for faster look since the answers json is overpopulated with form array in it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with the same thing, I figured it out this way.

In my situation since only the match query is subject to change I constructed match queries according to query parameters I am getting with following code.

```
var array = Object.entries(req.query)
    array.forEach(x => {
      var z = { [x[0]]: { $eq: x[1] } }
      matchTry.$and.push(z)
    })
```

output:

```
{
        "$and": [
            {
                "department": {
                    "$eq": "IT"
                }
            },
            {
                "gender": {
                    "$eq": "male"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Then use mongoose with it

```
const docs = await model
      .aggregate()
      .match(match)
      .exec()
    res.status(200).json({ data: docs })
```